# Getting a list of ALL plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get a list of ALL Wordpress plugins.

There is a function called `get_plugins()` but it will return all plugins that I have installed. What I need is a list of all plugins, no matter if I installed them before or not.

Is there a function that I could use? If not, is there a JSON, database, API or anything that I could use?

**Edit:**

```
var_dump(plugins_api('query_plugins', array(
    'per_page' => 100,
    'tag' => 'contact form 7',
    'number' => 5,
    'page' => 1,
    'fields' =>
        array(
            'short_description' => false,
            'description' => false,
            'sections' => false,
            'tested' => false,
            'requires' => false,
            'rating' => false,
            'ratings' => false,
            'downloaded' => false,
            'downloadlink' => false,
            'last_updated' => false,
            'added' => false,
            'tags' => false,
            'compatibility' => false,
            'homepage' => false,
            'versions' => false,
            'donate_link' => false,
            'reviews' => false,
            'banners' => false,
            'icons' => false,
            'active_installs' => false,
            'group' => false,
            'contributors' => false
        ))));
```

This returns a full of data that I don't need:

The only data that I need are the yellow marked keys below: `name` and `slug`

[image]

I know that I could get them out from the array but it would be very bad for the performance.

**Even when** I try it with a loop, I'll get 45 plugins but not more. Where is the rest???

```
foreach ($plugins as $plugin) { // $plugins is the variable of my code above but without 'tag' => 'contact form 7',
    foreach ($plugin as $p) {
        if ($p != null) {
            echo $p->name . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95841/114787), although it's a few years old. Some more info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/), and [here](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/09/the-plugins-directory-and-readme-txt-files/).

Comment: @MarsAndBack thank you, very good info! `https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/all-in-one-seo-pack.json` returns a JSON with all the information of the plugin "All in one SEO pack". But what would be the URL to get a list of all plugins? If you know it, please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: There is a plugin API which you can query for plugins like this: `$api = plugins_api( 'query_plugins', $args );` `https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_api/

Comment: @jrswgtr I have used `plugins_api('hot_tags'), array('page' => 90000000000, 'number' => 90000000000)`. It returns some plugins but not all.

Comment: try this: `$api = plugins_api( 'query_plugins', [  'per_page' => -1 ] )`

Comment: @jrswgtr I tried that but I get the following error: "An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this servers configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the <a href="http://wordpress.org/support/">support forums</a>."

Comment: The server probably can't handle receiving the data from 9000+ plugins. Try it with `'per_page' => 100`. If that succeeds that might indeed be the problem.

Comment: @jrswgtr that works but it returns ALL information about each plugin (description, images etc.). So it takes extremely long to load the page. What I need are only the slugs and the plugin names.

Comment: You can include/exclude fields with the `fields` argument. See the link I posted

Comment: @jrswgtr I have updated my question.

Comment: *"I know that I could get them out from the array but it would be very bad for the performance."* How do you know this? Have you tested this assumption? We're most likely talking the difference of a few kilobytes - unlikely to affect performance substantially.

Comment: @esqew a few kb times 9000 is a lot of kb

Comment: @esqew I know it, because my browser told me. It takes 2.14 seconds ... not the whole page, so the data only!

Comment: Reza @MarsAndBack,  you saved my day. Many many thanks for the hints that are so valuable to me. I am so happy. Many thanks for this overwhelming thread.  I am so glad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because getting all plugins at once will be too heavy for the server, it is a better idea to do it in steps.

You could do as many plugins at once as the server can handle. For the example I use a safe 100 plugins at once.

Everytime the script runs, it increments the "page" number with 1. So the next time the script runs the next 100 plugins are retrieved. The contents of the existing `plugins.json` will be parsed. The new plugins will be added (or overwritten if the plugin already is present) to the existing data, before encoding and saving it again.

If the page number is past the last, no results will be returned. This way the script knows there are no more plugins next. It then resets the page to 1, so it starts over.

I use the `wp_options` table to keep track of the pages, simply because it's the quickest way. It would be better to use some kind of filesystem caching. That will be easier to reset manually if needed.

You can set a **cronjob** to execute the script **every x minutes**. Now the `plugins.json` file will build up and grow step by step, every time it runs.

```
// get the current "page", or if the option not exists, set page to 1.
$page = get_option( 'plugins_page' ) ? (int)get_option( 'plugins_page' ) : 1;

// get the plugin objects
$plugins = plugins_api( 'query_plugins', [
    'per_page' => 100,
    'page'     => $page,
    'fields'   => [
       //.........
    ]
] );

// increment the page, or when no results, reset to 1.
update_option( 'plugins_page', count( $plugins ) > 0 ? ++ $page : 1 );

// build up the data array
$newData = [];
foreach ( $plugins as $plugin ) {
    foreach ( $plugin as $key => $p ) {
        if ( $p->name != null ) {
            $newData[ $p->name ] = [ 'slug' => $p->slug ];
        }
    }
}

// get plugin data already in file.
// The last argument (true) is important. It makes json objects into
// associative arrays so they can be merged with array_merge.
$existingData = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'plugins.json' ), true );

// merge existing data with new data
$pluginData = array_merge( $existingData, $newData );

file_put_contents( 'plugins.json', json_encode( $pluginData ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer and your code looks amazing! The JSON file contains 857 lines, which will be 285 plugins. Much more than my version with 45 plugins but in fact there are 56.163 plugins.

Comment: @RezaSaadati if the cron job keeps running the file will keep growing if it is right. How often does it run? And have you checked the file again?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that. This is definitely the best solution. Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's my pleasure. Have a nice weekend and happy coding! If you have any additional questions, ask them.

Comment: @RezaSaadati I updated my answer a bit. I hope to give you a bit more understanding about how my code works.

Comment: Thank you, that looks much cleaner now! You too, have a nice weekend. You deserved it :)

Comment: many many thanks for all you did dear friend i love this answer. It is so helpful to me. I love it for its versatile and very very nice and amazing design and approach. Keep up the great work !! Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Not the best answer but I tried to solve my own problem the best way I could.

## Getting a list of plugins

This will **not** return ALL plugins but it will return the **top rated** ones:

```
$plugins = plugins_api('query_plugins', array(
    'per_page' => 100,
    'browse' => 'top-rated',
    'fields' =>
        array(
            'short_description' => false,
            'description' => false,
            'sections' => false,
            'tested' => false,
            'requires' => false,
            'rating' => false,
            'ratings' => false,
            'downloaded' => false,
            'downloadlink' => false,
            'last_updated' => false,
            'added' => false,
            'tags' => false,
            'compatibility' => false,
            'homepage' => false,
            'versions' => false,
            'donate_link' => false,
            'reviews' => false,
            'banners' => false,
            'icons' => false,
            'active_installs' => false,
            'group' => false,
            'contributors' => false
        )));
```

## Save the data as JSON

Since the data that we get is huge and it will be bad for performance, we try to get the `name` and the `slug` out of the array and then we write it in a JSON file:

```
$plugins_json = '{' . PHP_EOL;
// Get only the name and the slug
foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
    foreach ($plugin as $key => $p) {
        if ($p->name != null) {
            // Let's beautify the JSON
            $plugins_json .= '  "'. $p->name . '": {' . PHP_EOL;
            $plugins_json .= '      "slug": "' . $p->slug . '"' . PHP_EOL;
            end($plugin);
            $plugins_json .= ($key !== key($plugin)) ? '    },' . PHP_EOL : '   }' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
$plugins_json .= '}';
file_put_contents('plugins.json', $plugins_json);
```

Now we have a slim JSON file with only the data that we need.

To keep updating the JSON file, we run that script to create a JSON file every 24 hours by setting up a Cron Job.

Comment: Looks good. Instead of concatenating strings you could put the data in nested arrays. Then when finished call `json_encode()` on it. Looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: If you still want all plugins I have a solution for you. I did not realize you were going to use cronjobs so I thought of a solution. If you are interested I will work it out for you in an answer.

Comment: @jrswgtr first I tried it with `json_encode()` but that included an array in JSON. Since I didn't want to have an array, I tried it that way. I am still interested in all plugins. If you have a solution, please post it as an answer. It would be very helpful!