# Parse and process HTML in PHP: fetching Wordpress-plugin-Metadata with a scraper

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, web-scraping

How do parse and process HTML in PHP - a simple scraper

I'm currently working on a parser to make a small preview of a page from a URL given by the user in PHP.

I'd like to retrieve only the title of the page and a little chunk of information (a bit of text)

**The project**: for a list of meta-data of popular wordpress-plugins (cf. https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/browse/popular/ and gathering the first 50 URLs - that are 50 plugins which are of interest! The challenge is: i want to fetch meta-data of all the existing plugins. What i subsequently want to filter out after the fetch is - those plugins that have the newest timestamp - that are updated (most) recently. It is all aobut acutality...

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms
https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database ....and so on and so forth.
```

[image: see the info of one page with meta-text-info]

so to take one page into consideration - fetching the meta-data of one Wordpress-plugin: With simple_html_dom ( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ) i guess that there is a appropiate way and method to do this without any other external libraries/classes. So far I've also tried using generally (DOM)-DOCDocument classes http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), loading the HTML and displaying it on the screen, and now i am musing about the proper way to do it.
i consider simple_html_dom ( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ) for this. It will make it very easy.
Here is an example of how to pull the title, and the meta-text(description).

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/');
$title = $html->find ("h1", class_="plugin-title").text];
$text  = $html->find(class_="entry-meta").text];

echo $title->plaintext."<br>\n";
echo $texte->text;
?>
```

see **the source**: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/
we have the following set of **meta-data** for each wordpress-plugin:

```
Version: 1.9.5.12 
installations: 10,000+    
WordPress Version: 5.0 or higher 
Tested up to: 5.4 PHP  
Version: 5.6 or higher    
Tags 3 Tags: database member sign-up form volunteer
Last updated: 19 hours ago
plugin-ratings
```

the project consits of two parts: the looping-part: looping over this URL https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/browse/popular/ and gathering approx 50 to 80 URLs (which seems to be pretty straightforward). the parser-part: where i have some issues - to get properly the data for the tags and the plugin-rating...

**update:** the plugins api. can help here - a great approach is
cf  [Getting a list of ALL plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990613/getting-a-list-of-all-plugins)

Comment: after more investigations i found out: 

The API is the proper way to get the metadata. However it is not very fast. For 50 calls it might take 1-2 min.  
I have the feeling that WP intentionally makes this call slow to discourage others from mining the plugin information. 



https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/345095/using-custom-code-how-can-i-fetch-data-from-the-wordpress-plugin-repo/345361#345361 - there some very nice examples are shoiwn

Comment: the plugins api. can help here  - a great approach is 
cf  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990613/getting-a-list-of-all-plugins